# Using If "II" to check for multiple possibilities of the same query

Tags: c#, if-statement

This is normally something I can find online pretty easily but I think I'm having trouble wording it so I apologize if this is a duplicate question.

I'm looking for a more concise way to do an IF/OR check for the same query.  For example:

```
if (sCheck == "string1" || sCheck == "string2" || sCheck == "string3")
{
   MessageBox.Show(sCheck + " is one of the three possible strings.");
}
```

I'm looking for a cleaner more concise way to do the same If/Or.  I was hoping something like these would work but of course they don't:

```
if (sCheck == "string1" || "string2" || "string3") { }

if (sCheck == ("string1" || "string2" || "string3")) { }
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Create a collection that holds the different possibilities:

```
if(new[] {"string1", "string2", "string3" }.Contains(sCheck)) { }
```

Answer (score 3):

You can create a collection of `string` and then use the `Contains` method:

```
List<string> myStrings = new List<string>(){"string1", "string2" , "string3"};
if (myStrings.Contains(sCheck))
{
   //Do Work
}
```

Comment: `in` statement in c#?

Answer (score 2):

It probably doesn't make much sense here, but in similar situations, `switch` can be useful:

```
switch (sCheck)
{
case "string1":
case "string2":
case "string3":
    MessageBox.Show(sCheck + " is one of the three possible strings.");
    break;    
}
```